# No Xelatex in texlive 2012

Tags: 12.04, latex

just installed texlive 2012 on my ubuntu and I have no **xelatex**.

There is one in Mac distribution. Is Ubuntu's "special"? I'll be glad for help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on what metapackage you've installed TeXLive with. There's basic ones, regular ones and full ones. I believe that the installation of `texlive-full` *does* pull XeLaTeX it in.

If you need the command-line tool `xelatex`, you'll just need to install [`texlive-xetex`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texlive-xetex).

---

To teach fishing, rather than feed you fish:

- Go to [`packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)
- Scroll down to **Search the contents of packages**
- select *packages that contain files whose names end with the keyword*
- fill in `xelatex`
- Hit search.
- Enjoy [the results](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xelatex&mode=&suite=quantal&arch=any), e.g.

  > ```
  > /usr/bin/xelatex   texlive-xetex
  > ```

Comment: To search descriptions from the command line, you can use `~d` in front of the search pattern. For example: `aptitude search ~dxelatex`

Comment: `apt-file search xelatex`