# Rendering CV template with XeLaTex

Tags: kubuntu, latex

1. Installed kubuntu on thursday
2. Installed LaTeX on my kubuntu machine, using `full`
3. Compiled an old document and it worked fine
4. Downloaded a CV template from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv
5. Compiled it, got error

   Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"

   The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.

   You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
   instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".

   See the fontspec documentation for further information.

   For immediate help type H .
6. Installed XeLaTex using this guide http://ledgersmb.org/faq/xelatex i.e.

7 Installed texlive-xetex that includes xelatex

```
apt-get install texlive-xetex

apt-get install liblatex-{driver,encode,table}-perl

apt-get install libtemplate-plugin-latex-per
```

8) Compiled CV template again, did not work. I got the same error as step 5.

Related: [No Xelatex in texlive 2012](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240119/no-xelatex-in-texlive-2012)

---

Excuse me if my question is not clear enough, I'm new to linux.

Comment: "Compiled CV template again, did not work." you got the same error as above?

Comment: Yes I got the same error as above

Comment: How are you compiling it? The tag says kubuntu, so are you using Kile?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so I have found [this answer](http://ledgersmb.org/faq/ubuntu). I hope it helps.